# Why can't I just assign the self pointer?

Tags: python, self

If you can help with this, I'd be much appreciated.
The following code outputs "7".
Why is that the reference to the object "a" doesn't change to Node with item = 9? Thank you.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,item):
        self.item = item
    def change(self):
        current = Node(9)
        self = current

a = Node(7)
a.change()
print(a.item)
```

Comment: `self` is not a pointer, Python *doesn't have pointers*. `self = current` simply assigns the object being referenced by `current` to the local variable `self`. then your method terminates. `a` doesn't change because you never do anything to change `a`. You can muck around with the global namespace if you'd like, but that would be highly irregular and I would say an antipattern

Comment: So, let's say I want to create a c++ like linkedlist, using just the class Node. Can't I remove the first node of the list?

Comment: "Why doesn't the language work this way" doesn't make a very good question for StackOverflow in general. It's designed the way it's designed. But to answer the follow-up question, you really should have a separate class tracking the head node. Keep in mind that the built-in standard library solution in c++, `std::list<>`, works that way.

Comment: @Rodolfo in the way you might do in in C++ no, but you could write another function which simply gets the next node and returns it, so `def remove_head(node): return node.next;` then `ll = remove_head(ll)`.

Comment: Anyway.. every LinkedList implementation of mine uses only single class "Node". And that's the way I learned (with c++ though).

Comment: @Rodolfo do you actually need a linked-list in Python? What would it be for? Anyway, I suggest reading the following link to get a good grasp of the semantics of Python, it's simple, but different from C++: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I will. Thanks again Juanpa.

Answer (score 0):

`self = current` only changes the name `self` to refer to the object referred by name `current`. It does not change the already instantiated class `Node(7)` which is referred by name `a` i.e. name `a` still refers to the same object `Node(7)`.

You can however return the `current` object and set as name `a`:

```
In [212]: class Node: 
     ...:     def __init__(self,item): 
     ...:         self.item = item 
     ...:     def change(self): 
     ...:         current = Node(9) 
     ...:         return current 

In [213]: a = Node(7) 
     ...: a = a.change() 
     ...: print(a.item)
9
```

But **this is mere name binding** (you can bind name `a` to any object you want).

Comment: Thank you. Let's say I have a linkedlist with just nodes (there is no class LinkedList). I wanted to the able to remove the first node of the LList. So, I have to change the reference of object "a" to the second node of the list. 
How can I accomplish that?

Comment: @Rodolfo `a = a.next`

Comment: That's outside the class.

Comment: @Rodolfo yes, and that's how you could do it. Again, *Python doesn't have pointers*. usually, to get the same effect, you would create an object. In your case, you could just use create a `LinkedList` class, which is standard practice even in languages like C++. Why do you not want to do that?

Comment: Alright. Thank you.
Although I couldn't solved it, now I know why.

Comment: I can in fact do it inside the class. I just have to change the inner states of first node to be equal to the second one and point the first node to the third node. But it's a gross solution.

Comment: @Rodolfo yes, I suppose that would have the same end effect, although I agree, quite gross.